# How to show encrypted user id in url in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, public-key-encryption

I created a URL to edit logged in user data here is my route:

```php
Route::get('/admin/create/user', [UserController::class, 'createUser'])->name('create.user');
Route::post('/admin/store/user', [UserController::class, 'storeUser'])->name('store.user');
Route::get('/admin/edit/user/{user_id}', [UserController::class, 'editUser'])->name('edit.user');
```

When a user clicks the edit button they get this URL.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/edit/user/160
```

If that user put 162 they can see another user's data!
How can I encrypt the user id, so that no one can see other user's data?

Here is my Controller's code:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Mail\UserActivatedEmail;
use App\Mail\UserBlockedEmail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Division;
use App\Models\District;
use App\Models\BloodGroup;
use App\Models\SscBoard;
use App\Models\Occupation;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Intervention\Image\Facades\Image;
use Xenon\LaravelBDSms\Facades\SMS;
use Xenon\LaravelBDSms\Provider\AjuraTech;
use Xenon\LaravelBDSms\Sender;


class UserController extends Controller
{

    public function storeUser(Request $request) {
        $request->validate([
            'role_id' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users',
        ]);

        $image = $request->file('profile_photo');

        if ($image) {
            $name_gen = uniqid() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($image)->save('backend/images/users/'.$name_gen);
            $save_url = 'backend/images/users/' . $name_gen;

            User::insert([
                'role_id' => $request->role_id,
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'phone' => $request->phone,
                'gender' => $request->gender,
                'occupation' => $request->occupation,
                'blood_group_id' => $request->blood_group_id,
                'ssc_year' => $request->ssc_year,
                'ssc_board_id' => $request->ssc_board_id,
                'ssc_role' => $request->ssc_role,
                'ssc_registration_no' => $request->ssc_registration_no,
                'present_division_id' => $request->present_division_id,
                'present_district_id' => $request->present_district_id,
                'present_address' => $request->present_address,
                'permanent_division_id' => $request->permanent_division_id,
                'permanent_district_id' => $request->permanent_district_id,
                'permanent_address' => $request->permanent_address,
                'description' => $request->description,
                'facebok' => $request->facebok,
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
                'profile_photo' => $save_url,
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            ]);
        } else {
            User::insert([
                'role_id' => $request->role_id,
                'name' => $request->name,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'phone' => $request->phone,
                'gender' => $request->gender,
                'occupation' => $request->occupation,
                'blood_group_id' => $request->blood_group_id,
                'ssc_year' => $request->ssc_year,
                'ssc_board_id' => $request->ssc_board_id,
                'ssc_role' => $request->ssc_role,
                'ssc_registration_no' => $request->ssc_registration_no,
                'present_division_id' => $request->present_division_id,
                'present_district_id' => $request->present_district_id,
                'present_address' => $request->present_address,
                'permanent_division_id' => $request->permanent_division_id,
                'permanent_district_id' => $request->permanent_district_id,
                'permanent_address' => $request->permanent_address,
                'description' => $request->description,
                'facebok' => $request->facebok,
                'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
            ]);
        }

        $notification = [
            'message' => 'User Created Successfully',
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        ];

        return redirect()->route('all.users')->with($notification);
    }

    public function editUser($user_id) {
        $roles = Role::all();
        $alldivisions = Division::get();
        $alldistricts = District::get();
        $allpdivisions = Division::get();
        $allpdistricts = District::get();
        $bgroups = BloodGroup::get();
        $sscboards = SscBoard::get();
        $ocupations = Occupation::get();
        $editUser = User::findOrFail($user_id);

        return view('admin.users.edit', compact('roles','editUser', 'ocupations', 'alldivisions', 'alldistricts', 'allpdivisions', 'allpdistricts', 'bgroups', 'sscboards'));
    }

    public function updateUser(Request $request) {
        $user_id = $request->id;

        $image = $request->file('profile_photo');
        $oldimage = $request->oldimage;

        $userToEdit = User::findOrFail($user_id);

        

        if($image){
            $name_gen=uniqid().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($image)->save('backend/images/users/'.$name_gen);
            $save_url = 'backend/images/users/'.$name_gen;
            if($oldimage){
                unlink($oldimage);
            }

            $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
            $user->role_id = $request->role_id;
            $user->name = $request->name;
            $user->email = $request->email;
            $user->phone = $request->phone;
            $user->gender = $request->gender;
            $user->occupation = $request->occupation;
            $user->blood_group_id = $request->blood_group_id;
            $user->ssc_year= $request->ssc_year;
            $user->ssc_board_id= $request->ssc_board_id;
            $user->ssc_role= $request->ssc_role;
            $user->ssc_registration_no= $request->ssc_registration_no;
            $user->present_division_id = $request->present_division_id;
            $user->present_district_id = $request->present_district_id;
            $user->present_address = $request->present_address;
            $user->permanent_division_id = $request->permanent_division_id;
            $user->permanent_district_id = $request->permanent_district_id;
            $user->permanent_address = $request->permanent_address;
            $user->description = $request->description;
            $user->facebok = $request->facebok;

            $user->profile_photo = $save_url;


            //$user->save();
            $this->authorize('save', $userToEdit);

        }else{
            $user = User::findOrFail($user_id);
            $user->role_id = $request->role_id;
            $user->name = $request->name;
            $user->email = $request->email;
            $user->phone = $request->phone;
            $user->gender = $request->gender;
            $user->occupation = $request->occupation;
            $user->blood_group_id = $request->blood_group_id;
            $user->ssc_year= $request->ssc_year;
            $user->ssc_board_id= $request->ssc_board_id;
            $user->ssc_role= $request->ssc_role;
            $user->ssc_registration_no= $request->ssc_registration_no;
            $user->present_division_id = $request->present_division_id;
            $user->present_district_id = $request->present_district_id;
            $user->present_address = $request->present_address;
            $user->permanent_division_id = $request->permanent_division_id;
            $user->permanent_district_id = $request->permanent_district_id;
            $user->permanent_address = $request->permanent_address;
            $user->description = $request->description;
            $user->facebok = $request->facebok;
            $user->profile_photo =$oldimage;

            //$user->save();

            $this->authorize('save', $userToEdit);

        }
        $notification = [
            'message' => 'User Updated Successfully',
            'alert-type' => 'success'
        ];

        return redirect()->back()->with($notification);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should rather make sure that user X can only see/edit user X's data. Since you seem to want to edit the logged in user there is no need to put the userId in the url - use `auth()->user()` in your controller to get the logged in user

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass the user ID to URL , Just do it like this:

```
public function editUser() {
    $roles = Role::all();
    $alldivisions = Division::get();
    $alldistricts = District::get();
    $allpdivisions = Division::get();
    $allpdistricts = District::get();
    $bgroups = BloodGroup::get();
    $sscboards = SscBoard::get();
    $ocupations = Occupation::get();
    $editUser = User::findOrFail(Auth()->user()->id);

    return view('admin.users.edit', compact('roles','editUser', 'ocupations', 'alldivisions', 'alldistricts', 'allpdivisions', 'allpdistricts', 'bgroups', 'sscboards'));
}
```

and for route :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/edit/user
```

And if you want to edit other user by your self or any other account you should manage the routes and access level in your project by using `Middleware` or some packages like `Spatie`.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Encryption`, You should restrict the data accessibility. Meaning, You only have to allow `User A` to access his/her data. If the user tries to access someone else's data, You should restrict the access.

**Create a `Middleware` to cross-check current user**

```php
class CurrentUserOnly
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        $currentUserId = Auth::user()->getId();
        $requestedUserId = $request->get("user_id");

        // Check the requestedUserId is identical to current user's Id
        if ($currentUserId !== $requestedUserId){
           // Access denied, Handle error
           return abort(403, 'Access denied');
        }
 
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Add the `Middleware` to `Routes`**

```
Route::get('/admin/edit/user/{user_id}', [UserController::class, 'editUser'])
     ->middleware(CurrentUserOnly::class);
     ->name('edit.user');
```

> Add your **Auth** middleware before **CurrentUserOnly** middleware to avoid getting `Auth::user()` as `NULL` in unauthenticated situations.

Comment: I used it, but it does not prevent the access. can you please help me on skype (mohiuddin3824) how can i use it?

Comment: If you blindly use it, It won't help. I didn't handle the condition. I updated the answer with a simple `abort`. Check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

While I suggest reading into authorization, and Laravel Gates/Policies, for a simple a quick solution you can use the `abort` function. This function will throw an exception that will stop the request from proceeding further.

```php
public function updateUser(Request $request) {
  abort_if(auth()->id() != $request->route('user_id'), 401);
  
  ...
}
```